# How to check an integer isn't bigger than MAX_VALUE when bing parsed with Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java, integer, numberformatexception

I am writing a Java program that takes a number from a user and performs calculations on it. I am taking the input with BefferedReader and I cannot use Scanner. The input string is parsed to an int value.

How can I check that the input string is not bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

It throws a NumberFormatException and I could handle this but that would also throw for any non-numberic input that would be handled differently.

```
default:
    input.push(Integer.valueOf(input_string));
    break;
```

Comment: Small nitpick: Java's naming conventions use camel case, so instead of `input_string` you should use `inputString`

Comment: Thank you. Good to know. I’ll change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to parse the value as a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and then use [intValueExact()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValueExact--) to turn it into an `int`:

```
int i = new BigInteger(inputString).intValueExact();
```

This throws `NumberFormatException` if the value is non-numeric, or `ArithmeticException` if the value is too big or small to store in an `int`.